# .Net Core 2.2 visual studio crashes when ajax is called

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, .net-core

I have an AJAX function

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Action",
    data: JSON.stringify(model),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: successFunc,
    error: errorFunc
});
```

then I have a controller with the action i want to call

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Action([FromBody] Model model)
    {
        var result = await service.DoSomething(model)
        var callbackUrl = "CallbackUrl";

        return Json(callbackUrl);
    }
```

success function of AJAX call

```
            function successFunc(callbackUrl) {
                window.location(callbackUrl);
            };
```

My problem is that when ajax post is invoked the application crashes with "The program '[17188] dotnet.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff)."

Interestingly the service's "DoSomething" method actually adds stuffs into database and callbackUrl is returned - all correctly

Putting breakpoint on service's line with "DoSomething" method in the Action doesn't work - application crashes before it can hit the breakpoint - the code is executed tho.

Any idea how could I find out what's wrong with this?

EDIT: the only thing that crashes is visual studio, IIS is still running

**EDIT2: tried to recreate the problem with brand new .net core web application**

step 1) create .net web application with individual user login

step 2) create ViewModel with string property "MyProperty" just to see passing parameters is ok

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

step 3) add new action to your controller

```
    public IActionResult SomeAction([FromBody] ViewModel model)
    {
        var callbackUrl = "callbackUrl";

        return Json(callbackUrl);
    }
```

step 4) add this to index.cshtml at the end of the file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var model = {
            MyProperty: "my random property"
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Home/SomeAction",
            data: JSON.stringify(model),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            processData: false,
            success: successFunc,
            error: errorFunc
        });

        function successFunc(result) {
            alert("success " + result);
        };

        function errorFunc(result) {
            alert("error " + result);
        };
    });
</script>
```

and it's working - have no idea why is VS crashing with mine example above it should be on the same principle

Comment: What is shown in your logs?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] (smallest possible complete set of web code that repros the issue).

Comment: First you can check in networks tab(XHR) of the browser to see it the request is getting fired or not.Then you can try commenting the doSomething code and return a hardcoded json from the action to see if this works. May be also try to invoke the action from some other tools like postman to make sure the code is fine from server side.

Comment: the moment ajax is invoked visual studio crashes but IIS still continues and the website is still running so request goes through fine

Comment: Couple of points:  1) Have you tried putting the break point on the first curly brace? 2) The url you mentioned is just "Action" have tried "Controller/SomeAction" 3) If your SomeAction method is copied from your code, its missing a semi colon at the end of the DoSomething line. Have you tried clean and rebuilding? 4) Copy in your working 2nd example into the failing project and see if it will working in there.

Comment: 1) doesn't hit
2) action gets called and executed - it's just visual studio that crashes
3) oh yeah, forgot that. cleaning and rebuilding didn't help
4) will try that

tahnks!